# INNER JOIN com campos iguais em uma tabela - Erro: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tb_usuario'

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, select, join

tenho 3 tabelas da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tb_usuario, tenho dois tipos de usuários (comprador, vendedor) em um campo ENUM para diferenciar o tipo de usuário.

No carrinho de compras tenho os IDs dos usuários, produto e número da transação. Relaciono 2 vezes para a tb_usuario para saber quem comprou e quem vendeu.

Quero realizar um SELECT que traga os nomes(comprador, vendedor, produto), mas quando realizo a query acontece os sequintes erro:

1 - SELECT tb_usuario.nome as 'comprador', tb_usuario.nome as 'vendedor', tb_produtos.nome as 'produto' FROM compras
    INNER JOIN tb_usuario ON compras.id_comprador=tb_usuario.id_usuario 
    INNER JOIN tb_usuario ON compras.id_vendedor=tb_usuario.id_usuario
    INNER JOIN tb_animais ON compras.id_produto=produtos.id_produto
Where id_compra=1;

**Erro: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tb_usuario'**

** Preciso criar uma tabela para cada tipo de usuário devido a os 2 alias iguais ?? **

Ou

2 - SELECT tb_usuario.nome as 'comprador', tb_usuario.nome as 'vendedor', tb_produtos.nome as 'produto' FROM compras
    INNER JOIN tb_usuario ON compras.id_comprador=tb_usuario.id_usuario 
    INNER JOIN tb_animais ON compras.id_produto=produtos.id_produto
Where id_compra=1;

Aqui retorna duas vezes o mesmo nome(sei que está errado pq não especifico que é o vendedor).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se é necessário criar 3 tabelas ou se há uma maneira de realizar a junção 2 vezes da tb_usuario com a produtos. Poderiam me ajudar

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que como você tem duas tabelas `tb_usuario` sendo relacionadas, você precisa dizer a qual delas se refere utilizando um alias para a tabela

```
SELECT comprador.nome as 'comprador',
       vendedor.nome as 'vendedor',
       produto.nome as 'produto'
  FROM compras compra
       INNER JOIN tb_usuario comprador ON compra.id_comprador = comprador.id_usuario
       INNER JOIN tb_usuario vendedor ON compra.id_vendedor = vendedor.id_usuario
       INNER JOIN tb_animais produto ON compra.id_produto = produto.id_produto
 WHERE compra.id_compra = 1
```

Note que determinei que a primeira `tb_usuario` será denominada como `comprador` e a segunda como `vendedor` apenas colocando um apelido logo após o nome da tabela.
Verificamos também que havia uma tabela `tb_produtos` sendo referenciada na relação de campos, e que não existe na cláusula `FROM` e/ou `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score -1):

Oi, bem provável que o seu erro está no fato de usar (INNER JOIN tb_usuario ) 2 vezes.

Porque não cria duas tabelas (compradores, vendedores) assim eles ficam separados. 
Na sua busca acredito que toda venda ou compra tem que estar relacionada a 1 vendedor e a 1 comprador.

Daí você usa (INNER JOIN compradores c ON ...) e (INNER JOIN vendedores v ON ...)
Assim você não terá mais o erro.

Dependendo da situação você pode optar por LEFT JOIN ou outros JOIN, mas aí é outra questão que acredito não vir a ser problema.

Comment: Não há necessidade de mudar a estrutura da tabela. O que falta é apenas o apelido para as duas